# How to create and run a jar file in different modes so that it can function differently?

Tags: java, jar, spring-batch, executable-jar

I'm a naive Java J2EE Developer. I have created a spring batch application which performs the below tasks:

1. Insert 10 records if row count in < 100
2. Insert 10 records (without validating existing row count)

I need to run Jar file in such a way that if I execute:

1. `java -jar HelloWorld.jar -threshold hello.properties` first step needs to be executed
2. `java -jar HelloWorld.jar -force hello.properties` second step needs to be executed

How to create a jar file such that it reads "threshold"/"force" and do specific operation? Please help.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: check hoe to use profiles in spring

Comment: Thanks for your reply @pvpkiran . But I want change the behavior of the Jar based during runtime. I assume spring profiles names are read from application.properties. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use profiles to define your steps and load them accordingly at runtime using the `spring.profiles.active` property. For example:

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class JobWithProfiles {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Bean
    public Job job(Step step) {
        return jobs.get("job")
                .start(step)
                .build();
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class Step1Config {

        @Autowired
        private StepBuilderFactory steps;

        @Profile("threshold")
        @Bean
        public Step step() {
            return steps.get("step")
                    .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                        System.out.println("executed in threshold mode");
                        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                    })
                    .build();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class Step2Config {

        @Autowired
        private StepBuilderFactory steps;

        @Profile("force")
        @Bean
        public Step step() {
            return steps.get("step")
                    .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                        System.out.println("executed in force mode");
                        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                    })
                    .build();
        }
    }

}
```

NB: you can also put the `@Profile` annotation on the configuration class.

Now if you run this app with `java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=threshold HelloWorld.jar hello.properties`, it should print: `executed in threshold mode`. Same with `force` profile.

For more details about profiles, please refer to this page: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

I hope this helps.